# How to run ethereum wallet on a light mode linux

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, light-clients

I just installed ethereum wallet and run from command line. After wallet started it began to download all blocks. Do I really need all that blocks to just use coins (not mining)? How can I use wallet on a lightweight mode?

PS I am running ubuntu 16.04 and wallet v0.8.10.

man ethereumwallet command does nothing

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Mist (AKA ethereumwallet) does not have a working light mode (as of Jan 14th, 2018). There are a few existing issues on github so I would expect that it should be fixed at some point.

If you have geth, you can run a light node with RPC enabled then connect to it from the wallet with `geth --light --rpc`, then start mist with `yarn dev:electron --rpc http://localhost:8545`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a similar question [here][1] which has been answered.
Basically, the answer is this:

```
geth --light
```

Comment: Would you update your answer to include the link to the similar question?